# Why do I receive a "no module named scipy" error even after I have installed the module via pip?

Tags: python, powershell, pip, scipy

I am using **Python 3.9** on **Windows 10** which I downloaded directly from the **Microsoft Store**.

I tried running a script in **PowerShell**: Bash *.sh
This script is supposed to tell my computer to execute a .py script which uses **scipy.io** and many other modules.

Then I received this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

My strategy was to make sure **pip** was up to date, then use it to install the desired packages, then run some commands to see if the packages were installed.

I ran this command to update pip:
`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

I ran this command to get some modules:
`python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose`

I also tried this command just in case:
`pip install scipy`

and got the result:

> Requirement already satisfied ...

I ran the command `pip list` to make sure **scipy** was in the list (and it was there).

Then I ran the command `python` and my prompt changed to ">>>" and entered `import scipy` and did not receive any errors.

I am very confused as to how I have **scipy** installed yet have my script tell me it isn't there. Please help!

Comment: You have multiple versions of python installed, try to clean that up

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted it looks like you have more than one python environment path in your system, because of which when you are installing these libraries they are installed at certain location while when you run the bash script it is using some other python location.
Try using these commands in both your terminal (cmd in windows) as well as in you bash script:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

This will give you the python environment path (location where your python libraries are present), then compare both the path you get from your terminal as well as bash. Add the path you got from the terminal to your global environment in order to make sure the same python version is used everywhere.

You can also refer to this: [Python modules not found over terminal but on python shell, Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378105/python-modules-not-found-over-terminal-but-on-python-shell-linux/30379595)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I do have multiple environments. Currently, I have anaconda and a python from the official website. I ran these commands and was returned a very long and hard to read list of file paths. But generally, they all have the form: C:\\Users, C:\\Program Files, etc. I am not sure which one to use.

Comment: Use the one which you got from the terminal i.e where you are able to import the libraries you want.

Comment: I ended up solving all the problems by just creating a dedicated environment using anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You might have multiple versions of python and you only installed scipy on the one you are not using
OR
you are using an IDE which has the option to use packages you install that are not by default in python. Pycharm has that. When you make a new project, it has a tick option saying "Inherit global site-packages" which means it will use additional packages you have installed any.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I do have the pycharm IDE but unfortunately, I am encountering this issue outside of pycharm.

Comment: did you check if you have multiple versions of python?

Comment: I do have multiple versions of Python. I have one installation from anaconda.org, then also one from python.org, possibly more. I'm currently trying to figure out which one to use.