# How to run a python code inside a bash script?

Tags: python

I am able to run a python code inside a folder as

```
python mycode.py
```

without problems (on MacOS).
However, I want to be able to run this code from anywhere else. So I define a small bash (`run_my_code`) script as follows

```
cd /path/to/my/folder
echo $PYTHONPATH
echo $PATH
pip list
pwd
python mycode.py
```

and run it as

```
run_my_code
```

which results in an `ModuleNotFoundError`. I checked and made sure that `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH` are the same in both environments. Even `pip list` list the same list of modules, even the one missing!!

How can I fix this module/path error?

I have answered my own question, but this only seems to be like a bad workaround. There must be a better way to fix this!

Comment: Which module isn't found ? One from your own code or from a library ?

Comment: Try to enter a venv and pip install -r requirements.txt in your bash script. Make sure to run the Python code with the interpreter that's in the venv.

Comment: @viper a pip installable library (`click`) is not found. But it is listed in `pip list`!

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/30379595/7384132?

Comment: I checked `PYTHONPATH`. They are the same!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but not sure it is a good solution:

1. You add the line

   ```
   print(sys.path)
   ```

   to your code to print out all the path's used in that environment when you run the code as `python mycode.py`.
2. You change your code to extend the paths at the very beginning of your code, i.e. like this

   ```
   import sys

   sys.path.extend(<here the output from step 1>)

   import <all the other imports>
   ```
3. Problem solved.

But is there a better way?